# Media player works in an activity that is not imported, initialized or has any code

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I use Media player in some activities and fragments in my app. Everything works fine with no problem. Import, start, stop, release.

**THE PROBLEM**

My home activity dont use MediaPlayer at all. Not import or any code relative. When i launch the app, music plays. Closing the app (onDestroy()) music stops. Launch activity again music starts. onStop() continue playing. Home activity is the MainActivity, first one laounching. How is this possible? Even if remains form other activity (no stop, no release or something) when i launch the first app activity (HomeActivity) shouldnt play anything.

Clarification

No need for code as it hasnt got any relation with media player.

**EDIT**

As asked i post the activity just in case:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.Auth;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ResultCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import eu.healthydev.triviaarena.Interface.RankingCallBack;
import eu.healthydev.triviaarena.Intro.PrefManager;
import eu.healthydev.triviaarena.Model.QuestionScore;
import eu.healthydev.triviaarena.Model.Ranking;
import eu.healthydev.triviaarena.Model.User;

public class UserProfile extends AppCompatActivity {

    private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    private FirebaseDatabase database;
    private ImageView userAvatar;
    private TextView userName;
    private TextView userScore;
    private TextView PvPScore;
    private TextView PvPWins;
    private TextView userClass, userGender, dateofJoin;
    private Button btnEnterDungeons;
    private String imageURL, user_class;
    long totalScore;
    private static String TAG = "";
    DatabaseReference questionScore, rankingTbl;
    int sum = 0;
    GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    PrefManager prefManager;  




    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
                .requestEmail()
                .build();

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
                .build();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        super.onStart();

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_profile);

        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getInstance();
        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        questionScore = database.getReference("Question_Score");
        rankingTbl = database.getReference("Ranking");
        prefManager = new PrefManager(this);

        //Checking whether a user as already Logged In
        if (firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() == null) {
            finish();
            //Starting the User Login Activity if the user is not Logged in
            startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
        }
        final FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();

        userAvatar = findViewById(R.id.userAvatar);
        userName = findViewById(R.id.nickName);
        btnEnterDungeons = findViewById(R.id.enterGame);
        userClass = findViewById(R.id.userClass);
        userGender = findViewById(R.id.user_genderA);
        userScore = findViewById(R.id.userScore);
        PvPWins = findViewById(R.id.pvpWins);
        PvPScore = findViewById(R.id.pvpScore);
        dateofJoin = findViewById(R.id.dateJoined);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitle("");
        toolbar.setSubtitle("");
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);




        btnEnterDungeons.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(UserProfile.this, GameChooseActivity.class);
                prefManager.setFirstTimeLaunch(false);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        });

        getData();

        updateScore(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getDisplayName(), new RankingCallBack<Ranking>() {
            @Override
            public void callBack(Ranking ranking) {
                //Update to Ranking table
                rankingTbl.child(ranking.getUserName())
                        .setValue(ranking);
                rankingTbl.child(ranking.getUserName()).child("avatar").setValue(imageURL);
                rankingTbl.child(ranking.getUserName()).child("user_class").setValue(user_class);
                //showRanking(); //After upload we will short ranking table and show result

            }
        });

        getScore();

    }


    //Method to get data from Firebase user and show them in profile
    private void getData() {
        final Context mContext = UserProfile.this;
        FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        String userid = user.getUid();
        final long joinedDate = user.getMetadata().getCreationTimestamp();
        final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd,yyyy HH:mm");
        final Date resultdate = new Date(joinedDate);
        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");
        reference.child(userid).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
                userName.setText(user.getUserName());
                userClass.setText(user.getUser_class());
                imageURL = user.getAvatar();
                Picasso.with(mContext).load(imageURL).into(userAvatar);
                dateofJoin.setText((sdf.format(resultdate)));
                PvPWins.setText(String.valueOf(user.getPvP_Wins()));
                PvPScore.setText(String.valueOf(user.getPvP_scores()));
                userScore.setText(String.valueOf(totalScore));
                userGender.setText(user.getUser_gender());


            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
        });
    }

    //Method to get the userScore from Ranking table in firebase
    public void getScore() {
        FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        String name = user.getDisplayName();
        DatabaseReference rankingScore;
        rankingScore = database.getReference("Ranking");

        rankingScore.orderByChild("userName").equalTo(name)
                .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        for (DataSnapshot data : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                            Ranking ranking = data.getValue(Ranking.class);
                            totalScore = ranking.getScore();
                        }


                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
    }

    private void updateScore(final String userName, final RankingCallBack<Ranking> callback) {
        questionScore.orderByChild("user").equalTo(userName)
                .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        for (DataSnapshot data : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                            QuestionScore ques = data.getValue(QuestionScore.class);
                            sum += Integer.parseInt(ques.getScore());
                        }
                        //After summary all score, we need process sum variable here because firebase is async DB
                        Ranking ranking = new Ranking(userName, sum, imageURL, user_class);
                        callback.callBack(ranking);
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.about_game:
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, AboutGameActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                return (true);

            case R.id.about_us:
                Intent intentus = new Intent(this, AboutUsActivity.class);
                startActivity(intentus);
                return (true);

            case R.id.switch_user:
                FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
                googleLogout();
                Intent switchuser = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(switchuser);
                finish();
                return (true);

            case R.id.logout:
                FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
                Intent logout = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(logout);
                finish();
                return (true);
        }
        return (super.onOptionsItemSelected(item));
    }

    public void googleLogout() {
        Auth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(
                new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResult(Status status) {

                    }
                });
    }



    }
```

As i said nothing to do with mediaPlayer. So completely exit the app, tap on application icon, this is the first activity, playing music.... I cant imagine how this is possible. Probably takes music from somewhere else...but how?

Comment: You have to provide [mcve]. Are you using any BaseActivity in your app ?

Comment: please provide proper details for the question it will help you...

Comment: Dont use any Base Activity. I ll add the activity that plays music, even its completely useless

Comment: @VipulChauhan You are right, but i really dont know what else to add. Meaning that as you can see in edit, mothing has to do with MediaPlayer.